# 4x2 images in one page

Tags: graphics, floats

I would like to make 4 rows and 2 columns of images in order to get 8 images as following:

[image]

the following image is made by:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC11}\par 
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC12}\par 
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC13}\par
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC14}\par
\end{multicols}
\caption{Simulation 1 - Frequency = 50Hz \qquad $\sigma_{T},\sigma_{D}=10^{-5}$}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC21}\par 
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC22}\par 
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC23}\par
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC24}\par
\end{multicols}
\caption{Simulation 2 - Frequency = 5Hz \qquad $\sigma_{T},\sigma_{D}=10^{-5}$}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

However, even when I make the images smaller, it generates a page just for it.
What I need is to insert a title above all of the images and that the title and images will be on the same page.

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of title - like a `\section` or `\chapter`?

Comment: yes. specifically here subsection

Comment: You could try to remove the `p` marker in the figure option, which tells LaTeX it is allowed to move the figure on its own page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the positioning option `h!` instead of `h`. This will relax the conditions for when a figure is too large to be put on a page together with other stuff.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\subsection{My title}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC1_NonLinear_Miss_ZEM}\par 
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC1_NonLinear_Hist_ZEM}\par 
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC1_NonLinear_Trajectory_ZEM}\par
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC1_NonLinear_Acc_ZEM}\par
\end{multicols}
\caption{Simulation 1 - Frequency = 50Hz \qquad $\sigma_{T},\sigma_{D}=10^{-5}$}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC2_NonLinear_Miss_ZEM}\par 
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC2_NonLinear_Hist_ZEM}\par 
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC2_NonLinear_Trajectory_ZEM}\par
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{MC2_NonLinear_Acc_ZEM}\par
\end{multicols}
\caption{Simulation 2 - Frequency = 5Hz \qquad $\sigma_{T},\sigma_{D}=10^{-5}$}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other options would be:

- to use the positioning option `H` from the `float` package (which essentially turns of the floating behaviour), or
- to not use a floating environment at all, i.e. leave `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` out and replace `\caption` with `\captionof{figure}`.

Answer (score 0):

mostly off-topic:

- you can organize your image without `multicol˙environments
- `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` add undesired vertical space, better is to use `\centering`
- figure placement `!ht` should resolve your problem

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\subsection{My title}
some text before image 
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{MC1_NonLinear_Miss_ZEM}
    \hfil
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{MC1_NonLinear_Hist_ZEM}

    \medskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{MC1_NonLinear_Trajectory_ZEM}
    \hfil
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{MC1_NonLinear_Acc_ZEM}
\caption{Simulation 1 - Frequency = 50Hz \qquad $\sigma_{T},\sigma_{D}=10^{-5}$}

    \medskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{MC2_NonLinear_Miss_ZEM}
    \hfil
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{MC2_NonLinear_Hist_ZEM}

    \medskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{MC2_NonLinear_Trajectory_ZEM}
    \hfil
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{MC2_NonLinear_Acc_ZEM}\par
\caption{Simulation 2 - Frequency = 5Hz \qquad $\sigma_{T},\sigma_{D}=10^{-5}$}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```